# Stopping save if "IF" clause is not fulfilled, instead of moving to next step

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a Template for users to fill in who aren't overly excel literate. I've incorporated VBA checks upon them clicking Save to ensure data integrity and formats are correct, but in turn I'm not overly VBA literate!

the first few Ifs terminate the save if the If is not fulfilled, but I have an issue with the last If, which is more of a Cautionary "Do you want to proceed if this % you've enterred is less than 1%" as in some cases, they may want to. If they click Yes, the document then saves, making the other checks redundant.

I'm using the code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
        Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim lngstatrows As Long

    'Checks if service consoles column has any zeros (If a site has been stated, they cannot have 0 consoles)

    If Lookup.[v1] > 0 Then
    MsgBox "ERROR: Sites are not allowed to have 0 consoles in Column O. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
    Cancel = True
    End If

    'Checks if all required fields have data in them, flags message box if not.

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B12:B1000]) <> (WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[c12:k1000]) + WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[M12:p1000])) / 13 Then
    MsgBox "ERROR: Required field has data missing, please check Columns B - P. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
    Cancel = True
    End If

    'Checks if Additive has 3 required fields enterred

    If DataInput.[B3] = "Additive" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B4:B6]) < 3 Then

    MsgBox "ERROR: If pricing is Additive, please populate Cells B4 - B6. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
    Cancel = True
    End If

    'Checks if Rebate% is less than 1% and asks for continue

    If DataInput.[B7] <> "" And DataInput.[B7] < 1 Then

    a = MsgBox("Rebate % is less than 1% - Are you sure you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo)
    If a = vbYes Then
    End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Desired result:
Nest the Terminate save IF's in the "Do you want to proceed" IF, so that if they click yes, the template still has to pass the other checks which just straight up cancel the save. (I've tried doing this myself but it didn't work, and now here I am!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tansform your `If … Then … End If` statemenst into one `If … Then … ElseIf …` statement.

This means if one of the first 3 conditions is `True` it cancels saving. If the first 3 are `False` and the 4ᵗʰ is `True` then it asks if they want to proceed. If they don't klick *yes* it will cancel save.

I all of these conditions are `False` it will not cancel and just save.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim lngstatrows As Long

    If Lookup.[v1] > 0 Then 
        'Checks if service consoles column has any zeros (If a site has been stated, they cannot have 0 consoles)
        MsgBox "ERROR: Sites are not allowed to have 0 consoles in Column O. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B12:B1000]) <> (WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[c12:k1000]) + WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[M12:p1000])) / 13 Then 
        'Checks if all required fields have data in them, flags message box if not.
        MsgBox "ERROR: Required field has data missing, please check Columns B - P. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf DataInput.[B3] = "Additive" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B4:B6]) < 3 Then 
        'Checks if Additive has 3 required fields enterred
        MsgBox "ERROR: If pricing is Additive, please populate Cells B4 - B6. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf DataInput.[B7] <> "" And DataInput.[B7] < 1 Then 
        'Checks if Rebate% is less than 1% and asks for continue
        a = MsgBox("Rebate % is less than 1% - Are you sure you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo)
        'if they don't click yes then cancel
        If a <> vbYes Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can combine all errors to one message.

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim CombinedErrors As String

    'Checks if service consoles column has any zeros (If a site has been stated, they cannot have 0 consoles)
    If Lookup.[v1] > 0 Then
        CombinedErrors = CombinedErrors & "ERROR: Sites are not allowed to have 0 consoles in Column O." & vbCrLf
    End If

    'Checks if all required fields have data in them, flags message box if not.
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B12:B1000]) <> (WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[c12:k1000]) + WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[M12:p1000])) / 13 Then
        CombinedErrors = CombinedErrors & "ERROR: Required field has data missing, please check Columns B - P." & vbCrLf
    End If

    'Checks if Additive has 3 required fields enterred
    If DataInput.[B3] = "Additive" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B4:B6]) < 3 Then
        CombinedErrors = CombinedErrors & "ERROR: If pricing is Additive, please populate Cells B4 - B6." & vbCrLf
    End If

    'if errors then cancel
    If CombinedErrors <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox CombinedErrors & "DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf DataInput.[B7] <> "" And DataInput.[B7] < 1 Then
        'Checks if Rebate% is less than 1% and asks for continue
        a = MsgBox("Rebate % is less than 1% - Are you sure you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo)
        'if they don't click yes then cancel
        If a <> vbYes Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked a treat! thanks for correcting the Code on my question too haha! Kind regards, J

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer before mine but I read your requirement slightly differently and this is what I modified your code to.

Here's hoping I fully understood your requirement.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim lngstatrows As Long

    'Checks if Rebate% is less than 1% and asks for continue
    If DataInput.[B7] <> "" And DataInput.[B7] < 1 Then
        a = MsgBox("Rebate % is less than 1% - Are you sure you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo)

        If a <> vbYes Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    If Not Cancel Then
        'Checks if service consoles column has any zeros (If a site has been stated, they cannot have 0 consoles)
        If Lookup.[v1] > 0 Then
            MsgBox "ERROR: Sites are not allowed to have 0 consoles in Column O. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
            Cancel = True
        End If

        'Checks if all required fields have data in them, flags message box if not.
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B12:B1000]) <> (WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[c12:k1000]) + WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[M12:p1000])) / 13 Then
            MsgBox "ERROR: Required field has data missing, please check Columns B - P. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
            Cancel = True
        End If

        'Checks if Additive has 3 required fields enterred
        If DataInput.[B3] = "Additive" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(DataInput.[B4:B6]) < 3 Then
            MsgBox "ERROR: If pricing is Additive, please populate Cells B4 - B6. DOCUMENT NOT SAVED"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed it the other way round in my answer because you don't need to bother the user with the percent question if the checks are not fulfilled and it will cancel anyway (just less clicking for the user). And I highly recommend to use `ElseIf` for the last 3 conditions. Save can be canceled immediately after one of the condidions is true, there is no need to check the others too if one is enough to cancel. (Saves time an clicking again).

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t mess with the multiple IF statements. I figure it all depends on what he requires. If he wants to provide the user with all errors then multiple message boxes is one way to do it.  As for the logic, I just tried to follow his stated requirement.

Comment: If the OP's intend is to show *all* errors. I recommend to concatenate all the error messages and show only one message box in the end, that is listing all errors for the convenience of the user. 3 boxes in a row just suck.

Comment: I don’t disagree. As I said, it’s one way to do it. I figured the question was less around that and more around the flow of messages. They may end up using a combination of our answers.

Comment: Hi Brad and PeH, both work, but I am going to go with PeH's answer in this case due to "don't need to bother the user with the percent question if the checks are not fulfilled and it will cancel anyway (just less clicking for the user)". Thank you both for taking the time to look at it though! PeH, how would I build the concat of all errors that have flagged into one error box? that sounds even more convenient for the user. I can raise a new thread if required!

Comment: @Jimmerding I added it to my answer, please have a look.